# Casex vs Casez in Verilog

Tags: verilog

what is the difference between `casex` and `casez` in `Verilog` ?
I have searched about it and find this sentence :

> casez treats all z values in the case alternatives or the case
>   expression as don't cares. All bit positions with z can also
>   represented by ? in that position.
>
> casex treats all x and z values
>    in the case item or the case expression as don't

cares.

for example , what is the difference between first one and second one:

1-

```
casez (instr)
7'b1zzzzzzz: // arithmetic
7'b01zzzzzz: // load-reg
7'b00zzzzzz: // store-reg
endcase
```

2-

```
 casex (instr)
    7'b1zxxxxzz: // arithmetic
    7'b01zzxxxx: // load-reg
    7'b00xxxzzz: // store-reg
    endcase
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Verilog Language Reference Manual (now replaced by the [SystemVerilog LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)) explains this in great detail. The key difference is when the *case expression* `instr` contains x or z values. Remember that both `casex` and `casez` look at both the *case item* **and** the *case expression* for x and z values. We call this a symmetric comparison as don't care values can show up in either place.

So if `instr` was all x's, none of the items in the `casez` would match, but *ALL* of the items in the `casex` would match, and a simulator would pick the first item. Similarly, if `instr` were all z's, then *ALL* items would match. I consider `casex` a useless construct.

SystemVerilog replaces both statements with a `case() inside` statement. It uses an asymmetric comparison operator `==?` that only treats an x or z in the *case item* as a don't care.

Comment: thanks for your answer.:) "Similarly, if instr were all z's, then ALL items would match."  does it happen in both casex and casez?@dave_59

Comment: Yes, it happens for both.