# Verilog: Changing multiple states in one case statement

Tags: logic, case, verilog, software-design, case-statement

Basically I'm trying to display the sum or product of two numbers (inputted using switches on an FPGA) onto a 7-segment display. I know that both my addition and multiplication bits work fine, as I've tested them separately.

I'm having trouble with the LSB though. No matter what it just defaults to F and never changes. I think Verilog doesn't allow me to modify both Cout1 and Cout0 in the same case statement. Is there a workaround for this? See my code, below.

```
always@*
    if (key1press)
    casex(PrintSum)

        // Hex 1 (MSB)
        // Works!
        5'b0xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1000000;  //0 if S[4] = 0
        5'b1xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1111001;  //1 if S[4] = 1

        // Hex 0 (LSB)
        // Doesn't work :(
        5'bx0000 : Cout0 = 7'b1000000;  //0
        ...
        5'bx1111 : Cout0 = 7'b0001110;  //F
        //default  : begin
        //            Cout1 = 7'b1000000;   //0 by default
        //            Cout0 = 7'b1000000;   //0 by default
        //end
    endcase
```

Thanks in advance everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simulations, case statements will execute first match. Everything will match the first two conditions (`5'b0xxxx`, `5'b1xxxx`).  If you move these conditions to the end, then they will never be reached as there will be a match in the `5'bx0000` to `5'bx1111` range.

There isn't overlap between the care bits. Therefore, the simplest solution is to split `Cout1` and `Cout0` into separate constitutional statements:

```
begin
  if (PrintSum[4]) begin
    Cout1 = 7'b1111001;  //1 if S[4] = 1
  end
  else begin
    Cout1 = 7'b1000000;  //0 if S[4] = 0
  end

  case(PrintSum[3:0])
    4'b0000 : Cout0 = 7'b1000000;  //0
    // ...
    4'b1111 : Cout0 = 7'b0001110;  //F
  endcase
end
```

---

Other things to be aware of:

- Don't use `casex`

  - [Casex vs Casez in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34370901/1959732)
  - read § 4.3 of [RTL Coding Styles That Yield Simulation and
    Synthesis Mismatches](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf)

    for details.
- `Cout0` and `Cout1` are inferred latches (level-sensitive). FPGAs have limited or no support for latches. Plus latches can be glitch prone if not done properly.

  - [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459413/1959732)
  - StackOverflow search result for [inferred latch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*verilog%5D+inferred+latch+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Thank you, this was all really helpful-and thanks for the extra resources too. I made the decision to swap out casex with casez.

Comment: You should clock the accept answer icon if this satisfies your question. It will help others with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

the following 2 terms from your case statement cover *all* possible values of the PrintSum selector. Since they are firs int eh list, no other values would ever be hit there.

```
    5'b0xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1000000;  //0 if S[4] = 0
    5'b1xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1111001;  //1 if S[4] = 1
```

You need to fix the above to provide meaningful values so that the other terms could execute as well.

you might also rearrange the items like this.

```
    // Hex 0 (LSB)
    // Doesn't work :(
    5'bx0000 : Cout0 = 7'b1000000;  //0
    ...
    5'bx1111 : Cout0 = 7'b0001110;  //F


   // Hex 1 (MSB)
    // Works!
    5'b0xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1000000;  //0 if S[4] = 0
    5'b1xxxx : Cout1 = 7'b1111001;  //1 if S[4] = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't both scenerios results in one value getting "hit" and ending the case then? (Also I tried switching the two items, no such luck unfortunately)

Comment: it will hit the first matching first. So, if PrintSum has 4 lower bits set to '0000', it will hit the first term. However for '00001' it will match the '0xxxx' term, and for '10001', the '1xxxx'.